# Ruby - block scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method which I want to act differently depending on the scenario, so I want to be able to pass a block to the method, and execute if the block is given.

However, I am confused by the scope of the variable in the block I am passing in.

For example:

```
def original_method (a, b, opt = {id: nil, id_map: {}})
  element_id = (opt[:id_map])

  yield if block_given?

end
```

And the new method which passes the block:

```
def new_method(a, b, opt)
 original_method (a, b, opt) do
  if(element_id.include? "some text")
    puts "it has some text"
  end
 end
end
```

But I get the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `element_id'
```

at the yield line.

Can this be done?

Comment: you are missing a closing parenthesis after `(opt[:id_map]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the local variable `element_id`, as `yield` s argument.

```
def original_method (a, b, opt = {id: nil, id_map: {}})
  element_id = opt[:id_map]
  yield(element_id) if block_given? # pass it as argument
end
```

Then accept it like :

```
def new_method(a, b, opt)
 original_method (a, b, opt) do | element_id | # receive as block pramater
  if(element_id.include? "some text")
    puts "it has some text"
  end
 end
end
```

`element_id` local variable has been created inside the method `original_method`, that is why it is accessible inside this method only.

Inside the method `new_method`, when you are calling the method `original_method` with a *block* attached to it, due to *closure* capability it has access to all variables inside the method `new_method` from begining to the point where the block is created.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your indirect question:

Blocks are scoped *lexically*, meaning that they have access to variables from the scope they're defined in (as opposed to "used in").